# How do I write a bash script to detect a mounted USB drive?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, cron

I'm triggering a script from cron.
I want it to run rsync ONLY if a USB disk called "data_3" is mounted,
otherwise not.

How do I write a bash script to detect a mounted USB drive ?

My current pseudocode:

```
#!/bin/sh  
if ( mount | grep /media/data_3 )  
  rsync ...  
else  
  echo "Failure"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close.

```
if mount | grep -q ' on /media/data_3 '; then
```

Don't forget the `fi` at the end (`help if` for details).

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it another way - find out the uuid of the disk by issuing the command when that usb is inserted first time (the objective is to find out the uuid) by using vol_id

> NAME
>          vol_id - probe filesystem type and read label and uuid
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          vol_id [--export] [--type] [--label] [--label-raw] [--uuid]
>   [--skip-raid] [--probe-all]
>   [--offset=bytes] [--debug] [--help]
>   [device]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          vol_id is usually called from a udev rule, to provide udev with the
>   filesystem type, the label and the
>   uuid of a volume. It supports most of
>   the common
>          filesystem formats and detects various raid setups to prevent the
>   recognition of raid members as a
>   volume with a filesystem.
>
> OPTIONS
>          --export
>              Print all values in key/value format to import them into
>   the environment.
>
> ```
>    --type
>        Print the filesystem type.
>
>    --label
>        Print the safe version of volume label suitable for use as
> ```
>
> filename.
>
> ```
>    --label-raw
>        Print the raw volume label.
>
>    --uuid
>        Print the uuid of a volume.
>
>    --skip-raid
>        Skip detection of raid metadata.
>
>    --probe-all
>        Probe for all types and print all matches.
>
>    --offset=bytes
>        Start probing at the given offset, instead of the beginning of
> ```
>
> the volume. The offset value is
>   specified in bytes.
>
> ```
>    --debug
>        Print debug messages to stderr.
>
>    --help
>        Print usage.
> ```
>
> ENVIRONMENT
>          UDEV_LOG
>              Set the syslog priority.
>
> EXIT STATUS
>          vol_id will only return successful if the value asked for is
>   not empty. All trailing whitespace
>   will be removed, spaces replaced by
>   underscore and slashes
>          ignored.

Then it's a matter of checking the vol_id once you have the value for that disk...